# Show half of next slide without Center Mode in Slick Slider

Tags: jquery, slick.js

What I want is to have a slider that shows 3.5 slides at once, with the right most slide being the one that is only half shown. I have seen something like this done successfully using centerMode and centerPadding with slick slider, but I do not want the slides to be centered. In other words, I want the left most slide to be flush with the side of the window, totally in view, but the right most slide to be half in the window, half off. Is this possible in slick? I've seen people using slidesToShow: 3.5, but this makes the left most slide go half off the screen and I need it on the right.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

No need to add "slidesToShow: 3.5 option"

Just call slick:-

```
$('.Your-container').slick({
    arrows: false,
});
```

and add following CSS:

```
.slick-list{padding:0 20% 0 0 !important;}
```

Either you can give a fixed padding to the right or percentage.

Comment: Thanks Abdul! Much cleaner solution.

Comment: That is such a time saver. God bless you.

Comment: Thank you.
However please note it won't work if you add the style directly in the browser via the inspector, in case you're trying to test it.  
You need to place it in the files loaded by the browser.

Comment: `.slick-list{padding:0 20% 0 0 !important;}` worked for me. As slick functionalityit self add `padding:0;` to the `.slick-list` class that overwrites our css.

Answer (score 65):

You can do something like this `slidesToShow: 3.5` and make `infinite: false`. The right most slide will be showing half.

Comment: The `infinite: false` does the trick, been banging my head on this for a while!

Comment: I just tried this and it shows half of the previous slide, not next,.

Answer (score 24):

You can also do this in slick by adding these two parameters in the slick init:

```
centerMode: true,
centerPadding: '20%',
```

This is the equivalent to

```
.slick-list{padding:0 20% 0 0;}
```

Comment: That's well and good, but note that the question asks for this layout without using centerMode.

Comment: It can't be equivalent of 0 20% 0 0, cause in your case you can see left and right slide. And in 0 20% 0 0 - only right.

Answer (score 5):

Please beware of using `slidesToShow` with decimal places.

According to [Official Documentation](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) `slidesToShow` is of type `int` and not `float`.
Using it as float is causing unpredictable exceptions on `breakpoint` event (when you have custom breakpoint option specified).

You can read more about those issue in official Slick GitHub threads [here](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/3313), [here](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/3677).

Comment: `slidesToShow`  is of type int

Comment: @DrewCordano yeah - this is what I stated in the comment above :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe need to add important in CSS.

Here is my JS code:

```
$(this).slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    infinite: true,
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    centerMode: true,
})
```

Here is CSS code:

```
.slick-list {
    padding:0 20% 0 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My use case is a bit different since I want to show portions of both the previous and next slides, *as well as* the arrows between the current slide and those slides.

What's working for me so far is adding these styles:

```
.slick-list {
  /* Show slides that would otherwise be hidden off-screen */
  overflow: visible;
}

.slick-slide:not(.slick-current) {
  /* Make slides other than the current one translucent */
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

It's a work-in-progress, but this was the only way I could find to show previous of both the previous and next slides.

Might be worth noting that the setting `lazyLoad: "ondemand"` is incompatible with this approach, as the preview slides' content won't be loaded until they're in the center.